# Any open source /free OCR(Pattern recognition) software? (for mobile platforms?)

Tags: iphone, design-patterns, ocr

I want to extract the text information (Chinese) from the images that picked by users with their mobiles. So I am here wondering is there any open source/free OCR (Pattern recognition) software for mobile platform. Currently I am doing with iPhone (And android, blackberry platform?)

I've searched stackoverflow but seems there only are some questions about C#/.Net

Thank you in advance~

Comment: Generally this is not done on the phone itself, but sent back somewhere to a server to be done and then the results pushed back to the device.

Comment: What about the Chinese hand-writing? How does it work? Doesn't need any library?

Comment: @Mickey: sure, needs a library (and probably a more complex one than for English writing). GrayWizardx was suggesting that the library lives on the backend server, instead of on the phone.

Comment: @Thilo, thank you. I'll think about the c/s architecture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're into writing your own solution, [this paper](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/project/pcvision/www/papers/chinese/final.html) seems to be applicable.

Answer (score 1):

ABBYY even has a mobile OCR SDK for iPhone, Android, and more, so you can recognize text on your device before using web services, at all: http://www.abbyy.com/mobileocr/
However, it is not free and you will have to buy a license for commercial purposes.

Answer (score 0):

GrayWizardx is right there are few servers that provide this kind of services like [kooaba](http://www.kooaba.com/using-kooaba/on-iphone/)

And may be it will be a bad idea to re-invent the whole wheel